# Is it possible to use @pytest.fixture to a test case?

Tags: python, pytest

let's say I have 2 test cases, the first one is test_log_in, and the other is test_log_out
and I want to use these cases before and after every single test case, I know we have pytest.fixture on conftest.py, but in this case test_log_in, test_log_out are test cases, and I do not want to put to conftest.py. is there any way to proceed with this approach?
a million thanks for your help!

```py
#here is my conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def appium_driver(request):
   pass

@pytest.fixture
def log_on_failure(request, appium_driver):
   pass
```

```py
#here is my test.py and I want to run test_login before every single test case and test_logout after every single test case
class Test_Login(base_test):

    def test_login(self, username, password):
        #test_login

    def test_logout():
        #test_logout
```

I have read pytest document but found nothing

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: why don't you want to make it a fixture? What problems to you anticipate? An alternative to fixtures is setup-methods in test-classes, but you probably know that.

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, I just wonder if we have any other way to do that, the reason that I dont want to put a test cases to conftest.py, can we create pytest.fixture outside conftest.py?

Comment: You can define fixtures inside the test module or test class where you use them, or in a local `conftest.py` if you want to want to use it in more than one test.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably what you need, as I see no reason to use a fixture as a test

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def log_in_out(username, password):
    print(f"log in {username}/{password}")
    assert 1 == 1
    yield
    print("log out")
    assert 1 == 1

class BaseTest:
    pass

#here is my test.py and I want to run test_login before every single test case and test_logout after every single test case
class Test_Login(BaseTest):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("username, password", [("user1", "pass1")])
    def test_something(self, username, password, log_in_out):
        print("test_something")
        assert 1 == 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to use @pytest.fixture as a test case.

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, could you please show me more details